# The fastest way to SELECT MAX( ) from table

Tags: aggregate-functions, abap, opensql

What would be the most efficient and elegant way to select MAX value from transparent table?
For example, let's try to select such simple table as T100, *Messages*. Let us imagine we should select maximum message number within some application area.
We can do this in a multiple ways. 
The most obvious is using `MAX` aggregate function

```
select MAX(msgnr)
from t100
where arbgb = '/ASU/GENERAL'
```

And the other is using `UP TO 1 ROWS` clause

```
select msgnr
from t100
where arbgb = '/ASU/GENERAL'
and ROWNUM = 1
order by msgnr DESC
```

Herein above, all SQL statements are given in a native Oracle SQL, as I was doing tests in DBACOCKPIT where this is mandatory.

Built-in cockpit tool showed almost identical results for both requests:

- *estimated costs* is 3 for both of them, however, second query has only 2 steps in plan whereas the first has 3.
- *estimated CPU costs* for the first query is 21.564 **per step**, however second has **total** cost of 21.964.

So we can conclude that second variant is more efficient here.
However, would this be a point in a common case? Would this result be different on different DBs or we can treat it as a rule of thumb?

Answer (score 4):

Performance measurements always vary depending on a rather large set of parameters, the DBMS being not the least of them. Some DBMS might, for example, be able to use an index to efficiently determine a `MAX(...)` statement while others might have to resort to some more inefficient form. Also, don't trust the optimizer's **predictions** - measure the real performance. The optimizer might be wrong for a number of reasons (outdated statistics and broken indexes being the most common ones as far as I have seen), and it's of little help if the optimizer **estimates** a total cost of 12.345 if the **actual** cost turns out to be 987.654. Hence, my recommendations would be

- select only what you need (avoid `SELECT *`, use `WHERE` sensibly)
- measure, measure, measure
- be wary of most of the unproven and alleged performance rules-of-thumb out there.